# Erlang lists:map behaving strange

Tags: erlang

Ok so here goes:

I got a piece of code like this:

```
A=lists:map(fun(Result) -> Result#o.prop1 
   end, ResultList),
B=lists:map(fun(Result) -> io:format("~p~n",Result#o.prop2),
   Result#o.prop2 
   end, ResultList),
io:format("~p ~p",[A,B])
```

Prior to this piece of code, there is a list of Results from a database search (each result has a prop1 value marked as "0" and a prop2 value marked as "74").

What happens is that A prints just right ("[0,0]") and while the first print of B elements one by one is right (two prints of "74") the list itself prints as "JJ" (these characters are always different in each execution)

If I remove the element by element print, or even if I switch the order (B's line and then A's line) I always get a messed up B.

Any help?

Comment: In what way is B messed up? I suggest you post an example of the messed up output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're seeing J instead of 74  is due to the fact that Erlang treats strings as lists of integers, and J is 74 (decimal) in ASCII.

```
1> io:format("~s~n", [[74, 74]]).
JJ
ok
2> io:format("~s~n", [[71, 72, 73, 74, 75]]).
GHIJK
ok
3> io:format("~p~n", [[71, 72, 73, 74, 75]]).
"GHIJK"
ok
```

Comment: printing it like this solved it: 
io:format("~p ~p",[[a|A],[b|B]])